# Exact Sequence of given jobIds list for VRP using Jsprit

Tags: java, spring-boot, constraints, vehicle-routing, jsprit

I have been trying to get exact sequence of jobs by giving list of jobIds, but it's not working.

I tried with a HardRouteConstraint as well as a HardActivityConstraint but in vain. I'm getting the sequence in the same route but not in the exact sequence as given in the jobIds list.

Can you please suggest some solutions for getting same order of given JobIds in a route ?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.